# Issue with setting tables remote ClearDB (heroku) database

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to migrate my app from a Cloud9 IDE to the Heroku platform. I'm able to serve up the page no problem but the page isn't loading any of the info that was supposedly migrated over. I'm not seeing any error messages, nor do I know how to check if the tables were created properly in ClearDB.

How do I make sure my tables were created properly and the data was loaded?

The following steps were taken:
-Get remote MySQL setup on Heroku with the ClearDB Ignite variant
-Change the database connection in my Express server to the credentials of my Heroku app (if/else that looks if CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL exists and connects using the Heroku app url)
-Dumped the database tables into a file and ran the file on the remote db:
-- mysqldump -uroot --no-data  > tables.sql
--mysql   -h"us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net" database  < tables.sql

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out. It looks like I exported the just the tables, not the entire database with values. I did a mysqldump for the entire database and then pushed it to heroku and everything appeared.